# Как заменить/изменить все байты в каком то файле?

Tags: c++, замена, байты, удаление

Как можно изменить или заменить значение байтов в каком то файле? Либо тем самым удалить файл?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Поменять байты в файле можно, конечно. Но даже если там останется 0 байт, он сам не удалится, просто будет пустым.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Такое тоже в принципе можно было бы сделать, но что для этого использовать в коде?

Comment: Вы уж решите — изменить или удалить...

Comment: Любая запись в файл - это "изменение байт", а по работе с файлами полно туториалов. Или я вопрос не понял?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я видел только туториалы где например в текстовик тупо что то написать, или создать файл, удалить, а мне нужно конкретно напрямую изменить байты в файле

Comment: [`std::fstream::write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) или [`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwrite) чтобы записать байты. [`std::fstream::seekp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp) или [`fseek`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fseek) чтобы выбрать, в какую позицию писать.

Answer (score 1):

Если удалить — то просто [`std::filesystem::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove).

Если изменить байты — просто переписать файл заново или поверх определенного места.

Но сдается мне, что вы хотите что-то третье, и получается XY-проблема...